# Execute a Delay between cron job entries in cron.sh

Tags: cron

I have a file with 4 cron tasks which I was advised to create as my hosting company only allows 3 scheduled tasks. So I have created this one file with 4 tasks but I would like to add a gap or delay between them. Perhaps 30 minutes.

Is this possible and how can I do this...

The sample code is below:

```
/usr/bin/php5 "/home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/xyz/cron1.php"
/usr/bin/php5 "/home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/xyz/cron2.php"
/usr/bin/php5 "/home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/xyz/cron3.php"
/usr/bin/php5 "/home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/xyz/cron4.php"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a sleep between them, `sleep 1800`.

Do note that your host might start complaining about this long running cron job, especially if they have a sequential execution of cron jobs...

A better solution I think would be to pass some arguments to the job and use those arguments to determine which jobs to run. Then the cron job would execute alot more frequently, but return faster.
Say that you give the cron job the current time and then use that information to decide which scripts to execute.